# assigning hashtags to django models

Tags: python, django

I have defined Job model in my django website as shown here:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Skills required by a job:

```
class SkillsGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name


class Skill(models.Model):
    skill_group = models.ForeignKey(SkillsGroup)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill_group.group_name + ' - ' + self.name
```

Now my problem is how could I assign each Job a list of skills (Like hashtags or ...) so that each user can find jobs according to a specific skill.
Something like the way Tags are assigned to each question in stackoverflow.

Is there anyway I could implement this feature without using external apps/libraries?

Comment: I used to use [this](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) back in the day when I used Django. It looks like it's still being maintained. It's not the only tagging solution out there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need ManyToManyField. I will simplify a bit your example.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title    

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

You can now add or remove required skills to your job like this, but be sure that Skill instance is already saved in a database or create it right in a "skills" property of Job instance:

```
job = Job.objects.get(title="My Vacancy")

# Create a new skill for my job offer
job.skills.create(name="Special Skill")

# Add an existing skill to my job offer
skill = Skill.objects.get(name="Another Special Skill")
job.skills.add(skill)

# I've changed my mind, I don't need the last skill to my vacancy
job.skills.remove(skill)
```

This field can act like Queryset also:

```
# Check required skills for a job
skills = job.skills.all()

# Lets find some job with special skills 
jobs = Job.objects.filter(skills__name__icontains="Special Skill")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want `Skill` to be a `ForiegnKey` to `Job`.

Comment: My problem is that each skill could be assigned to many jobs. and skills are predefined in the website

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you will want to take a look for this django app:
[django-tagging](http://django-tagging.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I was wondering if there were any ways I could implement this feature without using external apps/libraries?

Comment: @ErfanGholamian well.. if u want follow classical relational theory, u should create additional tables for all skills, all jobs, and for relations between them  like user-skills, skills-jobs. For my point of view it's hardest way to do this. Or you can store all skills in char field(or in case of postgre in Array field), and create some app-logic to process that. 
Using existing apps -- pythonic way.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, thanks for pointing me for that. But please, keep in mind, that new users w/ rep < 50 can't comment other peoples posts.

Comment: @allin I'm very well aware as every new user with <50 rep tells me this when I make such a comment. As should be obvious, the rep bar is there for a reason, and not having enough rep to do something does not give you a license to misuse parts of the site in order to work around it, **especially answers**. It's not that hard to earn 50 rep anyway. You've already done it since I left this comment.